# Blazor 6.0 await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List CS8601 Possible null reference asignment

Tags: entity-framework, async-await, blazor, nullreferenceexception

Hello Everyone im missing something fairly fundamental here and i could really appreciate some guidance .

I am fairly new to Blazor and the entity framework and am building one of my first Blazor apps

I have a fairly basic data class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BIDM2.Data
{
    public class InvalidAddressMapping
    {
        [Key]
        public int record_no { get; set; } = 0;
        public string sales_org_pos { get; set; } = " ";
        public string press_sales_mgr_code { get; set; } = " ";
        public string press_sales_mgr_Name { get; set; } =  " ";
        public string forming_sales_rep_code { get; set; } = " ";
        public string forming_sales_rep_Name { get; set; } = " ";

    }
}
```

that i am using in my controller as follows

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task <ActionResult<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>> GetInvalidAdressMappings()
        {
            return await _db.GetInvalidAddressMappings.FromSqlRaw("EXEC BIDM_GetInvalidAddressMappings;").ToListAsync();
        }
```

and im trying to use it in my razor page like this

```
@code {
    List<InvalidAddressMapping> invalidMappings = new List<InvalidAddressMapping>();


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
            invalidMappings = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>(NavigationManager.BaseUri + "invalidmapping");  
    }
}
```

how ever  when i try and run my razor page  im getting an error CS8601 Possible null Reference asignment   :(

Im not sure i totaly understand  and i could use some guidance to point me in the right direction  it has to be somethign fairly fundamental i am missing

interestingly this all came about because im trying to convert an existing non async method  to an async method

when i use

```
  //1. get invalid address mappings  
        public InvalidAddressMapping[] GetInvalidAddressMappings() 
        {
            InvalidAddressMapping[] invMappings;
            // exec BIDM_GetInvalidAddressMappings calls the stored procedure 
            invMappings = _dbcontext.GetInvalidAddressMappings.FromSqlRaw("EXEC BIDM_GetInvalidAddressMappings;").ToArray();
            return invMappings;
        }
    }
```

it works beautifully and i can see a lovely list of JSON data

please help a struggling old git out  and pint me in a direction where i can understand where i am going wrong :)

thank you every one

Comment: `GetFromJsonAsync` returns a nullable type. If it fails to deserialise properly for example, it could return null. The code is telling you that you need to check for a null response to be safe.

Comment: Is it Blazor Server? Because, if it is to use `GetInvalidAdressMappings` on pages on the server, it would probably be better to define it in a Service, not as a controller. Or both if the controller is necessary at some point.

Answer (score 3):

The [`GetFromJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-json-httpclientjsonextensions-getfromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpclient-system-string-system-threading-cancellationtoken)) extension method returns a *nullable* type. In your case, it is `List<InvalidAddressMapping>?` (note the extra `?` on the end there). If it fails to deserialise properly, for example, it could return null. The code is telling you that you need to check for a null response to be safe.

So the safe version is to do something like this:

```
var result = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<InvalidAddressMapping>>(
    NavigationManager.BaseUri + "invalidmapping");

if(result == null)
{
    // Do something here to handle this error, for example:
    throw new Exception("Can't get data from the server for some reason, help!");
}

invalidMappings = result;
```

Also note that the CS8601 message you see is a warning, not an error. So technically you could ignore it, though I would strongly advise against doing that.